# How many vCPUs can be allocated from the AMD 8 core FX 8350?

Tags: cpu, 64-bit, virtualization, vmware, hyper-v

I have never gotten a proper explanation of vCPUs. What I mean is take the AMD FX 8350 for example. It has 8 cores. I know I can add 1 vCPU per virtual machine on a Hypervisor. But is there a limit to the amount of vCPUs that can be allocated per physical processor?

If there is a limited how is that figured out?

What happens when you add more than one vCPU to a virtual machine? I mean what is happening below the configuration? How does the processing change when there is 1 vCPU vs more than one vCPU?

Comment: "If there is a limited how is that figured out?" - You are limited to the amount of physical CPUs you have.  "What happens when you add more than one vCPU to a virtual machine?" - You are able to use multiple physical processors.(which does not apply to your specific case).  "ow does the processing change when there is 1 vCPU vs more than one vCPU?" - There is no difference.

Comment: With ESXI, you can overbook cores (assign more vcpus/vcores than you have aggregately across your VMs), but this leads to unintended side effects for SMP operations; the hypervisor will not allocate processing to the task until enough physical cores are available to run the request. VMWare tracks a statistic called "CPU Ready" which refers to the wait time the VM experiences while the host is waiting to arrange to have sufficient free cores to perform the task across all the CPUs the VM thinks it has. Its best not to overbook, or to use single core VMs where possible if you do.